# AutoclickerInGame - Why Dont work?

Tags: c++, bots

i am trying to do bot who will press the keys automatically, when the game is open. In notepad this program works well, but in Metin2 it does nothing. Do u have some ideas, what is wrong?

```
int main()
{
clock_t start = clock();
clock_t start_grab = clock();
HWND handle = NULL;
handle = FindWindow(0, "PandoraMT2.pl");
if (handle != 0)cout << "well";
for (int i = 0; i < i + 1; ++i)
{
    handle = GetActiveWindow();
//  SendMessage(handle, WM_CHAR, VK_SPACE, 0);
    if ((clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC == 1)
    {
        keybd_event(VK_SPACE, 0,  0  , 0);  
        keybd_event(VK_SPACE, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        start = clock();
    }
    if ((clock() - start_grab) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC == 6)
    {
        keybd_event(VkKeyScan('Z'), 0, 0, 0);
        keybd_event(VkKeyScan('Z'), 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        start_grab = clock();
    }
}
```

Comment: `i < i + 1` What in the world is that ? Never saw something like that before.

Comment: I had while(1), i dont remember why i changed on it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Games might not rely on the windows message queue for their keystate / mouse state. e.g. two possible choices in windows are :

```
GetKeyState
```

or

```
GetAsyncKeyState
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx

From GetKeyState:

> The key status returned from this function changes as a thread reads key    messages from its message queue. The status does not reflect the interrupt-level state associated with the hardware. Use the GetAsyncKeyState function to retrieve that information.

So, GetKeyState reads the state according to what happened in the message queue, while GetAsyncKeyState directly reads the hardware interrupts (whether the physical keys are up or down, this includes mouse keys). The message queue supports input buffering, e.g. the keys in the queue can be laggy. For this reason many game devs might prefer GetAsyncKeyState for realtime games, and those games won't receive your fake key press events.

Comment: Ok, so by GetAsyncKeyState i can find out about key state, but program still do nothing in game. Now i know that when game is open simulator dont press keys. Do u have some ideas, where is my problem and how can i deal with it?